# Regex to capture entire string after second instance of a slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that takes the form of a path, for example:

```
Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name
```

I need to produce a string which is everything after the second forward slash. From the example above that means that my desired output would be:

```
Writing / How to write your name
```

I have seen a number of questions/answers regarding outputting the last part of a URL or getting a specific folder name in a file path but none of them have worked for me so far. I'll admit that my research hasn't been extensive due to time contraints.

My first thought is to do this in javascript with something like:

```
var input = "Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name";
var firstCut = input.substr(input.indexOf('/') + 1);
var secondCut = firstCut.substr(firstCut.indexOf('/') + 1);
```

I would prefer a more elegant solution, preferably using regex if possible!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `replace`ing approach:

```js
var s = "Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name";
var result = s.replace(/^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}\s*/, '');
console.log(result);
```

The pattern will match (and `.replace` will eventually remove it):

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^\/]*\/){2}` - two occurrences of

  - `[^\/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
  - `\/` - a `/` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

In case there is no match, the result will be equal to the input string.

A matching approach might look like

```js
var s = "Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name";
var result = (m = s.match(/^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}\s*([\s\S]+)/)) ? m[1] : "";
console.log(result);
```

The `([\s\S]+)` pattern will capture into Group 1 any one or more chars up to the string end *after* the initial text has matched the pattern described above.

In case there is no match, the result will be an empty string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will return an array in the form `[entire string match, captured group]`. It starts at the beginning of the string and matches two groups of any number of characters that aren't `/` followed by a `/`, then captures the rest of the characters from there to the end of the string.

```js
let test = "Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name"

let result = /^(?:[^\/]+\/){2}(.+)/.exec(test)[1]

console.log(result)
```

That said, the best answer is probably to use a `split` and a `join`:

```js
let test = "Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name"

let result = test.split(/\s*\/\s*/).slice(2).join(" / ")

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works well! I am going to accept Wiktor's answer above as his doesn't include a leading white space and I prefer the use of match/replace to exec. Up vote for this answer though!

Comment: @Drummad Besdies, `.` does not match line break chars.

Comment: Cool, makes sense. I also just realized that none of us gave you the easiest method, I'll update with it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why would there be line breaks in a path?

Comment: @jmcgriz We do not know the specs for the posted string. In a general case, we should consider all possible scenarios.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "I have a string that takes the form of a path" - OP's first line

Comment: @Drummad Updated to include the `split` method of doing this, probably the cleanest way

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^.*?\/.*?\/` to remove the part you don't want.

Ex.

```js
    var string = 'Year 1 / English / Writing / How to write your name';
    var result = string.replace(/^.*?\/.*?\//, '');
    console.log(result);
```

if you want to capture the group use `^.*?\/.*?\/(.*)$`

[RegExpr Link](https://regexr.com/3ul4p)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid I get an error in the console when I run it though: "Invalid regular expression: missing /".

Comment: I was missing a slash at the end of the regex, it's fixed now.